# Getting List<T> from object[] in generic method

Tags: c#, arrays, list, generics

I'm trying to write a method that gathers all the results of paginated API calls for any type into a list. My method looks like this so far...

```
        private async Task<List<T>> AggregateResults<T>(string url)
        {
            var results = new List<T>();

            var morePages = true;
            while (morePages)
            {
                var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaginatedResult>(responseContent);

                results.AddRange(result.results.Cast<T>().ToList());

                if (result.paging != null)
                {
                    url = result.paging.next.link;
                }
                else
                {
                    morePages = false;
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
```

the Paginated Result class looks like this

```
{
    public class PaginatedResult
    {
        public object[] results { get; set; }
        public Paging? paging { get; set; }
    }

    public class Paging
    {
        public Next next { get; set; }
    }

    public class Next
    {
        public string after { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I'm passing in things like this as the generic for the method

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

I'm getting this error right now `'Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type` .
Is there any way I can get a List from an object[] here?

I've tried casting the array about any way I can find and keep running into errors. I've thought about inheriting from `PaginatedResult` in my classes that I'm trying to get in lists, but can't wrap my head around how that would work or if it would.

Comment: `responseContent` is a valid `PaginatedResult`? With a string `Name` and a list or array of objects?

Comment: Side note: you are missing a bunch of `using` to dispose stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making `PaginatedResult` a generic class `PaginatedResult<T>`, and change results type from `object[]` to `T[]`. You can then just `AddRange(result.results)`, no need to use `Cast<T>` or call `ToList`

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string j = """
{
    "results": [
        { "name": "a", "DateOfBirth": "2000/01/01" },
        { "name": "b", "DateOfBirth": "2000/01/01" },
    ],
    "paging" : {
        "next": {
            "after": "...",
            "link": "..."
        }
    }
}
""";
            var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaginatedResult<Person>>(j);
            Console.WriteLine(res.results[0].Name);
        }

        public class PaginatedResult<T>
        {
            public T[] results { get; set; }
            public Paging? paging { get; set; }
        }

        public class Paging
        {
            public Next next { get; set; }
        }

        public class Next
        {
            public string after { get; set; }
            public string link { get; set; }
        }
        public class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked a charm. thanks friend.